# razor view @Html.RadioButtonFor

Tags: c#, razor

I have the following bit of Razor code:

```
@{
    foreach(var item in ModelBasket.AvailableOptions)
    {
      if (item.Enabled)
      {

      }
    }
}
```

each item has a Selected property and description property.
I want to create a radio butoon for each item but if I try and do the following in my if statement:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(item.Description, item.Selected, new {@class = "radio__input" })
```

it just red lines under item.Description with cannot resolve item.

Just to test in my if statement if I put `<p>item.Description</>` then this is literally what gets rendered and not the item description as I'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the method parameter requires a lambda, such as:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(item => item.Description, new {@class = "radio__input" })
```

Comment: Still receive the same error. When I look on item in this context it seems as though item is being ignored from the parent. i.e. it wants to go ModelBasket.AvailableOptions

Comment: Apologies - I dont think my overloaded example is supported in MVC 5.2.  The supported overloads are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobuttonfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2.  Basically, you must provide a `object` value - then there are three options: providing either an `object` or `IDictionary` for the htmlAttributes (or no attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add the option checked. 
`@Html.RadioButtonFor(item => item.Description, new {@class = "radio__input", @checked = item.selected })`

Comment: red lines under Description and on item where @checked =

Comment: try "@checked="checked" and see if the radio button is checked, if it works you have to something like @checked=item.selected ? "checked":""

Comment: still the same as before. doesn't like item description

Comment: Use this @Html.RadioButtonFor(item=> item.selected,item.selected, new {@class = "radio__input", id=item.Description}) and to the label use the 'labelFor'. Hope it works this time